# Dependency Property UserControl Binding not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

My project is implemented in MVVM. I have a MainWindow, which consists of a statusbar and a tabview. Inside the tabview, there is a UserControl called "AnnotationView". Annotationview is the parent of two smaller usercontrols, called TimePicker. TimePicker consists of two textboxes, one for hours and one for minutes. I want to use this UserControl two times (that's also why I made it a Control of its own, to reuse it later on).

XAML of TimePicker:

```
<UserControl x:Class="archidb.Views.TimePicker"
             x:Name="TimePickerControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"
             KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=TimePickerControl}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"
                 Text="{Binding Path=HourValue}"
                 x:Name="tbHours"
                 KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="0"/>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}"
                   Margin="0 -3 0 5"
                   Text=":"
                   Grid.Column="1"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}"
                 Text="{Binding Path=MinuteValue}"
                 x:Name="tbMinutes"
                 KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

TimePicker Code-Behind:

```
public partial class TimePicker : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HourValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("HourValue", typeof(string), typeof(TimePicker), new PropertyMetadata("00"));
    public string HourValue
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HourValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HourValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MinuteValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MinuteValue", typeof(string), typeof(TimePicker), new PropertyMetadata("00"));
    public string MinuteValue
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MinuteValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MinuteValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public TimePicker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

In the AnnotationControl, I insert the UserControls like this:

```
<v:TimePicker x:Name="tpStart"
              HourValue="{Binding Path=StartHours}"
              MinuteValue="{Binding Path=StartMinutes}"
              KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2"/>

<v:TimePicker x:Name="tpEnde"
              HourValue="{Binding Path=EndHours}"
              MinuteValue="{Binding Path=EndMinutes}"
              KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="3"
              Grid.Row="2"/>
```

DataContext of AnnotationControl is set to its viewmodel, where I declared the properties.

The problem is, the binding is not working. The default value I set in the dependency property ("00") is not showing in any of the textboxes. Also if I write something in the textboxes, the property in the viewmodel of AnnotationControl doesn't change its value. This problem has been bugging me for several days now, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to simply use a [`RelativeSource Binding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource(v=vs.110).aspx) in your `UserControl` and to *NOT set it's `DataContext` to itself*:

In your control:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding HourValue, RelativeSource=
    {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourPrefixToBeAdded:TimePickerControl}}}"
    x:Name="tbHours" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="0" />
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlockStyle}" Margin="0 -3 0 5" Text=":" 
    Grid.Column="1" />
<TextBox Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" Text="{Binding 
    MinuteValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type 
    YourPrefixToBeAdded:TimePickerControl}}}" x:Name="tbMinutes" 
    KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" />
```

Then you will be able to data bind the properties from outside the control.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sadly, it still does not work. I changed the binding in TimePicker and removed the DataContext setting from the grid.
The properties of AnnotationControl's viewmodel still show null value when debugging. Do I also need to change the bindings in AnnotationControl XAML maybe?

Comment: You could add `Mode=TwoWay` if you need changes to be reflected outside the control, but that shouldn't stop it from working. What errors do you have in the Output Window in Visual Studio?

Comment: Mode=TwoWay added to the Binding in AnnotationControl.xaml did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way:
Remove that line:

```
DataContext="{Binding ElementName=TimePickerControl}"
```

Bind like this:

```
"{Binding ElementName=TimePickerControl, Path=HourValue}"
```

Another way: (cleaner)

Set it in TimePicker constructor:

```
  (this.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;
```

Bind like this:

```
"{Binding HourValue}"
```

After some reading, your example should be working so I assume you didn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged for your ViewModel, "00" is not shown because binding works, properties are set to default and their values are not updated.

Comment: Thats not working either. I did actually implement INotifyPropertyChanged in a BaseViewModel class, but the viewmodel for TimePicker is currently empty.

Comment: `DataContext = this;` is the worst advice you can give anybody trying to use databinding correctly.  Please don't.  Anybody reading this, you will cause yourself pain and suffering with this advice.  Don't do it.

Comment: Will, I suppose it's you who gave me minus, but you are wrong. I don't set UserControl's DataContext. I set Content.DataContext which means I actually set DataContext of first UserControl's child. It doesn't break databinding, everything works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, in the UserControl constructor, set the DataContext to itself:

```
public TimePicker()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   this.DataContext = this;
}
```

Also, remove this from your grid in the user control:

```
DataContext="{Binding ElementName=TimePickerControl}"
```

The DataContext of your user control has already been set within the user control itself, therefore when you use the following code:

```
HourValue="{Binding Path=EndHours}"
```

You are actually asking "Bind to EndHours in the UserControl's DataContext."

You need to change the binding so that it looks at the DataContext of the parent window. Give the parent window a name and use the following:

```
HourValue="{Binding DataContext.EndHours, ElementName=windowName}"
```

Comment: In addition, I would say that in UserControl DataContext shouldn't be changed.

Comment: Did you mean the "first" UserControl AnnotationView? If yes, I've tried your suggestion and that sadly didn't work.

Comment: @Zbigniew if I remove the DataContext from TimePicker, I get a bindingexpression path error.

Comment: @refl3x Have you set the UserControl's DataContext to itself? Using either: this.DataContext = this; Or the XAML varient?

Comment: The DataContext of the Control named AnnotationView is set to it's viewmodel. The DataContext of Timepicker is unset, but the DataContext of the grid contained in Timepicker is set to the TimePicker element, as in the question.

Comment: I just edited my question, the TimePicker-Control XAML didn't show fully, the header was missing.

Comment: Ok, in the constructor of the user control, have you set the DataContext of the control to itself? (this.DataContext = this;)

Comment: Alternatively, in the XAML header, you can do this: DataContext="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}}"    (Not 100% if that is the correct xaml)

Comment: No I didn't. I set these in XAML. Here is how I set the DataContext of AnnotationControl:
        <UserControl.DataContext>
            <vm:AnnotationViewModel/>
        </UserControl.DataContext>

Comment: FFS, never never EVER `DataContext = this;`.  You just broke databinding.  Simply give your root element an x:Name and use Binding.ElementName to point there.  Please, do everybody a favor and delete this.  This meme needs to die.

Comment: @Will I've just tried this and this works nicely, so thanks for sharing. Despite your unnecessary burst of rage.

Comment: All my bursts are completely necessary.